# TSQL - Find rows matching AND / OR filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find the best way to do this within SQL (or whether SQL is the recommended route to take at all)

I have a couple tables, with a structure as explained below (de-normalized for explaining ease). One is a table of employees with their "tag" definitions. The second is a table of employee groups, along with the criteria for the group.

### Employee Table

```
    EmployeeId      |   Tags
    ----------------------------- 
    1               |   Country|US
    1               |   EmployeeType|FullTime 
    2               |   Country|CA
    2               |   EmployeeType|FullTime
    3               |   Country|BR
    3               |   EmployeeType|FullTime
    4               |   Country|US
    4               |   EmployeeType|FullTime
    4               |   Language|Spanish
```

### Group Table

```
    GroupId         |   Tags                           |    OperatorGroup
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    1               |   Country|US                     |    D68BF531-FD9B-4A0E-886E-7420BDFFE380
    1               |   Country|CA                     |    D68BF531-FD9B-4A0E-886E-7420BDFFE380
    1               |   EmployeeType|FullTime          |    0B97D792-7659-42EF-8036-D19B1A0D5197
    2               |   Country|BR                     |    CE61BC17-2567-4B02-AE5E-F5EA40265EE7
    2               |   EmployeeType|FullTime          |    6A3418F6-C4FD-40E2-97B3-0F9E87759939
    3               |   Country|US                     |    BF3DAC05-8131-463F-976E-28099628842D
    3               |   EmployeeType|FullTime          |    D63CEDC2-D15F-4E05-B3B9-0109121B3C75
    3               |   Language|Spanish               |    3AA247D1-3779-48BD-8A2C-B9C8A084E32D
```

In the above table "Group", OperatorGroup determines the condition / operator for that group. Within the same GroupId, I use the OR operator within the same OperatorGroup, and the AND operator otherwise. For GroupId == 1, both Country|US and Country|CA has the same OperatorGroup, hence would be joined by an OR clause, in words, "You will match GroupId = 1 if your country is (US OR CA) AND you are a full time employee"

The result that I am looking for is the groups that the employee is part of. Based on the above data, I would expect the below

EmployeeGroups Result

```
    EmployeeId         |   GroupId
    ------------------------------
    1                  |   1
    2                  |   1
    3                  |   2
    4                  |   1
    4                  |   3
```

Is a SQL-only solution (TSQL - SQL Server 2012) too ambitious? Any pointers either way would be much appreciated.

---

I should add that the tag names (Country, EmployeeType and Language) are just examples, I can have the tag names and values (US, CA etc...) added run time.

Comment: This seems like a case where I'd question the effectiveness of doing it in SQL. If this is something where you do not care (too much) about performance, I'd say you can build the SQL dynamically in a string and execute that. If performance is important - it seems a better data model (e.g. a better normalized model) would be better and/or handling such logic in the application code

Comment: What would be a better data model if keeping the logic in SQL is preferred?

Comment: Well - for starters, your employee table should likely have a field/attribute called "Country" which can have the value US. Unless an employee can "belong" to multiple countries, then you'll need a 1:M relation ship mapped. EmployeeType should also be a field/attribute which can have the value e.g. FullTime (or maybe that's just an enum, so 1 for FullTime and a translation table with the value 1, FulLTime) . Similar for Language.  Once you have that, a lot of things will be a lot easier

Comment: Ah. That was my attempt to clarify the scenario. The values in the columns actually point to an numeric value, called a TagId. TagId appears in both the tables above. Does that help any?

Comment: How the `EmployeeId = 4` gets `GroupId = 1`?

Comment: EmployeeId:4 matched the criteria for GroupId == 1 which is (Country == US or CA AND EmployeeType == FullTime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. I had to change the schema and the rules of the group table a lil bit

**Group Table**

```
GroupId         |   Tags                           |    OperatorGroup
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1               |   Country|US                     |    D68BF531-FD9B-4A0E-886E-7420BDFFE380
1               |   EmployeeType|FullTime          |    D68BF531-FD9B-4A0E-886E-7420BDFFE380
1               |   Country|CA                     |    0B97D792-7659-42EF-8036-D19B1A0D5197
1               |   EmployeeType|FullTime          |    0B97D792-7659-42EF-8036-D19B1A0D5197
2               |   Country|BR                     |    CE61BC17-2567-4B02-AE5E-F5EA40265EE7
2               |   EmployeeType|FullTime          |    CE61BC17-2567-4B02-AE5E-F5EA40265EE7
3               |   Country|US                     |    BF3DAC05-8131-463F-976E-28099628842D
3               |   EmployeeType|FullTime          |    BF3DAC05-8131-463F-976E-28099628842D
3               |   Language|Spanish               |    BF3DAC05-8131-463F-976E-28099628842D
```

Each unique OperatorGroup within a value of GroupId represents a complete set of rules that match a specific group. That way I can pivot my employee and group tables and do a join to find matching groups.

I have pasted my schema data + queries below.

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]([EmployeeId] [int], [EmployerId] [int] NOT NULL, [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeTag]([EmployeeTagId] [int], [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL, [TagId] [int] NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employer]([EmployerId] [int], [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group]([GroupId] [int], [EmployerId] [int] NOT NULL, [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GroupDefinition]([GroupDefinitionId] [int], [GroupId] [int] NOT NULL, [TagId] [int] NOT NULL, [Grouping] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tag]([TagId] [int], [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, [Value] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)
```

**Data**

```
INSERT [dbo].[Employer] ([EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'Fabrikam')

INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (1, 1, N'John Smith')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (2, 1, N'Jane Miller')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (3, 1, N'Nelda Maughan')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (4, 1, N'Joe Anderson')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (5, 1, N'Ami Mcmanis')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (6, 1, N'Charlena Ashbaugh')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (7, 1, N'Matt Tutino')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (8, 1, N'Sulema Alexandria')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (9, 1, N'Ema Wolak')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (10, 1, N'Marinda Krejci')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (11, 1, N'Felipa Chew')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (12, 1, N'Armand Hosier')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (13, 1, N'Roland Blunk')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (14, 1, N'Ellen Frasier')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (15, 1, N'Nicolle Tarbell')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (16, 1, N'Christopher Lautenschlage')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (17, 1, N'Nelson Maughan')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (18, 1, N'Wes Boyd')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (19, 1, N'Jason Lessley')
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (20, 1, N'Jesus Purves')

INSERT [dbo].[Tag] ([TagId], [Name], [Value]) VALUES (1, N'Country', N'United States')
INSERT [dbo].[Tag] ([TagId], [Name], [Value]) VALUES (2, N'Country', N'Canada')
INSERT [dbo].[Tag] ([TagId], [Name], [Value]) VALUES (3, N'Country', N'Brazil')
INSERT [dbo].[Tag] ([TagId], [Name], [Value]) VALUES (4, N'EmployeeType', N'Full Time')
INSERT [dbo].[Tag] ([TagId], [Name], [Value]) VALUES (5, N'EmployeeType', N'Part Time')
INSERT [dbo].[Tag] ([TagId], [Name], [Value]) VALUES (6, N'Language', N'Spanish')
INSERT [dbo].[Tag] ([TagId], [Name], [Value]) VALUES (7, N'Language', N'French')
INSERT [dbo].[Tag] ([TagId], [Name], [Value]) VALUES (8, N'Language', N'English')

INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (2, 1, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (3, 1, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (4, 2, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (5, 2, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (6, 2, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (7, 3, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (8, 3, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (9, 3, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (10, 4, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (11, 4, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (12, 4, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (13, 5, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (14, 5, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (15, 5, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (16, 6, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (17, 6, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (18, 7, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (19, 7, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (20, 7, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (21, 8, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (22, 8, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (23, 9, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (24, 9, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (25, 9, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (26, 10, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (27, 10, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (28, 11, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (29, 11, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (30, 11, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (31, 12, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (32, 12, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (33, 12, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (34, 13, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (35, 13, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (36, 13, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (37, 14, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (38, 14, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (39, 14, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (40, 15, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (41, 15, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (42, 15, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (43, 16, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (44, 16, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (45, 17, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (46, 17, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (47, 18, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (48, 19, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (49, 19, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (50, 20, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (51, 20, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeTag] ([EmployeeTagId], [EmployeeId], [TagId]) VALUES (52, 20, 6)

INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (1, 1, N'US Full Timers')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (2, 1, N'CA Full Timers')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (3, 1, N'NA Spanish Full Timers')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (4, 1, N'NA French Full Timers')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (5, 1, N'US Part Timers')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (6, 1, N'CA Part Timers')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (7, 1, N'NA Spanish Part Timers')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (8, 1, N'NA French Part Timers')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (9, 1, N'BR Spanish Full Timers')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (10, 1, N'Spanish Speakers')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (11, 1, N'US Employees')
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([GroupId], [EmployerId], [Name]) VALUES (12, 1, N'BR Employees')

INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, N'8e336244-94ac-4e62-a719-0a4a0b01a6f2')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (2, 1, 4, N'8e336244-94ac-4e62-a719-0a4a0b01a6f2')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (3, 2, 2, N'b3c87fe8-7b9f-4648-9708-20a460cf9314')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (4, 2, 4, N'b3c87fe8-7b9f-4648-9708-20a460cf9314')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (5, 3, 1, N'36fa7924-fa11-4772-b632-84c79b6bbb1b')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (6, 3, 4, N'36fa7924-fa11-4772-b632-84c79b6bbb1b')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (7, 3, 6, N'36fa7924-fa11-4772-b632-84c79b6bbb1b')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (8, 3, 2, N'dfa7f0f9-aa7a-401b-8bfd-804aeadff1a9')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (9, 3, 4, N'dfa7f0f9-aa7a-401b-8bfd-804aeadff1a9')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (10, 3, 6, N'dfa7f0f9-aa7a-401b-8bfd-804aeadff1a9')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (11, 4, 1, N'b857e999-0a7e-49fe-b138-88aed2d81aa3')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (12, 4, 4, N'b857e999-0a7e-49fe-b138-88aed2d81aa3')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (13, 4, 7, N'b857e999-0a7e-49fe-b138-88aed2d81aa3')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (14, 4, 2, N'296741c2-de6f-46ca-adcc-5b552fb4b0eb')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (15, 4, 4, N'296741c2-de6f-46ca-adcc-5b552fb4b0eb')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (16, 4, 7, N'296741c2-de6f-46ca-adcc-5b552fb4b0eb')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (17, 5, 1, N'48fd52d4-141a-43d3-8dea-69b9df6337ed')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (18, 5, 5, N'48fd52d4-141a-43d3-8dea-69b9df6337ed')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (19, 6, 2, N'e85ba82a-0ca7-410b-ba35-726bd86a8621')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (20, 6, 5, N'e85ba82a-0ca7-410b-ba35-726bd86a8621')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (21, 7, 1, N'bb656fc1-8ccd-4ff6-85ec-185216b55e9f')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (22, 7, 5, N'bb656fc1-8ccd-4ff6-85ec-185216b55e9f')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (23, 7, 6, N'bb656fc1-8ccd-4ff6-85ec-185216b55e9f')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (24, 7, 2, N'8333dc24-4850-40d9-8b34-86c5d33bca60')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (25, 7, 5, N'8333dc24-4850-40d9-8b34-86c5d33bca60')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (26, 7, 6, N'8333dc24-4850-40d9-8b34-86c5d33bca60')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (27, 8, 1, N'e060b0e9-759f-4fe5-80d8-3fb2a73df6c8')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (28, 8, 5, N'e060b0e9-759f-4fe5-80d8-3fb2a73df6c8')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (29, 8, 7, N'e060b0e9-759f-4fe5-80d8-3fb2a73df6c8')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (30, 8, 2, N'33854572-3081-4e1c-ae98-fa15b2bc86b3')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (31, 8, 5, N'33854572-3081-4e1c-ae98-fa15b2bc86b3')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (32, 8, 7, N'33854572-3081-4e1c-ae98-fa15b2bc86b3')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (33, 9, 3, N'a4bfd6b8-556a-4e01-b3e8-b725a85c458c')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (34, 9, 4, N'a4bfd6b8-556a-4e01-b3e8-b725a85c458c')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (35, 9, 6, N'a4bfd6b8-556a-4e01-b3e8-b725a85c458c')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (36, 10, 6, N'649c0f7a-a5d3-4713-9335-8be57137347e')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (37, 11, 1, N'54c43caa-67a6-4be3-b237-2a89423360c8')
INSERT [dbo].[GroupDefinition] ([GroupDefinitionId], [GroupId], [TagId], [Grouping]) VALUES (38, 12, 3, N'd282d453-9671-408e-b6c6-d36296369a2e')
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @employerId INT = 1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pivotedEmployeeTags') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #pivotedEmployeeTags;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pivotedGroupDefinition') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #pivotedGroupDefinition;

CREATE TABLE #pivotedEmployeeTags (EmployeeId INT, Name NVARCHAR(50), Country INT NULL, EmployeeType INT NULL, [Language] INT NULL)
CREATE TABLE #pivotedGroupDefinition (GroupId INT, Name NVARCHAR(50), Country INT NULL, EmployeeType INT NULL, [Language] INT NULL)

;WITH FlattenedEmployeeTags AS
(
    SELECT 
        Employee.EmployeeId
        ,Employee.Name
        ,Tag.TagId
        ,Tag.Name as TagName
    FROM Employee
        LEFT JOIN EmployeeTag ON EmployeeTag.EmployeeId = Employee.EmployeeId
        LEFT JOIN Tag ON Tag.TagId = EmployeeTag.TagId
    WHERE EmployerId = @employerId
)
INSERT INTO #pivotedEmployeeTags
    SELECT 
        EmployeeId
        ,Name
        ,Country = MAX( CASE WHEN TagName = 'Country' THEN TagId END )
        ,EmployeeType = MAX( CASE WHEN TagName = 'EmployeeType' THEN TagId END )
        ,[Language] = MAX( CASE WHEN TagName = 'Language' THEN TagId END )
    FROM FlattenedEmployeeTags
    GROUP BY EmployeeId, Name

;WITH FlattenedGroupDefinition AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Group].GroupId
        ,[Group].Name
        ,Tag.TagId
        ,Tag.Name as TagName
        ,Grouping
    FROM [Group]
        LEFT JOIN GroupDefinition ON GroupDefinition.GroupId = [Group].GroupId
        LEFT JOIN Tag ON Tag.TagId = GroupDefinition.TagId
    WHERE EmployerId = @employerId
)
INSERT INTO #pivotedGroupDefinition
    SELECT 
        GroupId 
        ,Name
        ,Country = MAX( CASE WHEN TagName = 'Country' THEN TagId END )
        ,EmployeeType = MAX( CASE WHEN TagName = 'EmployeeType' THEN TagId END )
        ,[Language] = MAX( CASE WHEN TagName = 'Language' THEN TagId END )
    FROM FlattenedGroupDefinition
    GROUP BY GroupId, Name, Grouping
    ORDER BY GroupId, Grouping

SELECT 
    EmpTags.EmployeeId
    , GrpTags.GroupId
FROM 
    #pivotedEmployeeTags EmpTags
    INNER JOIN #pivotedGroupDefinition GrpTags 
        ON 
            (GrpTags.Country = EmpTags.Country OR GrpTags.Country IS NULL)      
            AND (GrpTags.EmployeeType = EmpTags.EmployeeType OR GrpTags.EmployeeType IS NULL)           
            AND (GrpTags.[Language] = EmpTags.[Language] OR GrpTags.[Language] IS NULL)
ORDER BY EmpTags.EmployeeId, GrpTags.GroupId
```